# When WebView is added to a specific view in NSWindow, :hover stops working. How can I fix this?

Tags: cocoa, webview, webkit, nswindow

If I create a WebView and add it to NSThemeFrame like so:

Let window be the NSWindow instance I'm adding to:

```
NSView * themeFrame = window.contentView;
[themeFrame.superview addSubview:myWebView];
```

Then any :hover tags of elements in the page I load doesn't work anymore. However, the :hover does appear on mouseDown/mouseUp. So maybe this is a refresh issue. I tried calling [myWebView setNeedsDisplay:YES] in mouseMoved: but no luck.

Is there something special about contentView? I tried the same thing with an NSView and overrode its mouseMoved: method while calling setNeedsDisplay and the NSView handled mouseMove fine. Is there something special about :hover?

Any ideas or ramblings are welcome!

I might have the same problem as [Cocoa WebView on os X not firing mouse hover events without having to click and hold left mouse key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191279/cocoa-webview-on-os-x-not-firing-mouse-hover-events-without-having-to-click-and?rq=1) but there's no answer there.

Comment: Any progress on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and after debugging and reading the source of WebKit, I found a solution. The crucial part seems to the [WebHTMLView class](http://opensource.apple.com/source/WebKit/WebKit-6531.9/mac/WebView/WebHTMLView.mm), specifically the method `-[WebHTMLView _updateMouseoverWithEvent:]`. There's a check whether the view's window is a key window and sure enough, my window wasn't key even though I called `makeKeyWindow` on it.

My window was a child window of a document window and to solve the hover issue, I created a `NSWindow` subclass and overrode `isKeyWindow` like this:

```
- (BOOL)isKeyWindow
{
    return [super isKeyWindow] || [[self parentWindow] isKeyWindow];
}
```

This made hover work in WebView in my document's child window.